# LED check circuit on startup

Tags: led, testing, test, self-test

I wanted to use a sensor which should indicate low fluid level with a LED.

I don’t want to have a non working LED in that circuit and want it to be automatically checked everytime the circuit powers up for the first time.

Is there a self test circuit, like the lights in the dashboard of your car, which can check if the LED is still good and goes of after a few seconds?

Comment: Unlike incandescent lamps, which fail open, LEDs fail both open and short. So you will have two conditions to check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use arduino why dont you do this start-up test in code? If you have still reason here can be some inspiration. After powering this circuit the Led starts to glow immediatelly, then after C1 charges to 4.3v the transistor become off aswell as Led. You can connect the Led to your fluid controll circuit according your needs.

Change R1 according your led wattage and power supply voltage.

Green is current thru Led, blue is the Cap voltage:

[image]

[image]

Edit:

For fast discharging the Cap to repeat cycle you can add a reverse connected diode D2 to discharge Cap thru R4 once the power supply is disconnected.

[image]

[image]

Edit:

Maybe more suitable would be an NPN version of this circuit. It is possible control Led with whatever voltage in range 2-12v. (0v the Led is off).

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. youre right. I made a mistake by mentioning arduino. I dont need it. The circuit you provided is exactly what i need. Do these circuits have a name so i could lookup other versions of it online?

Comment: and also i want the led to go out suddenly like pn the dashboard of cars.

Comment: another feature the lights on the dashboard have is that no matter how often and how fast you switch the ignition on and off. The lights go on for few seconds and go off immediately. So the capacitor would have to discharge very fast ionce ignition is turned off in order to make the circuit make work again on startup.

Comment: I added discharging in Edits. Remember, after start-up check you have to control Led thru point i depicted in first schematic (top of R1) by aplying voltage to this point.

Comment: In next edit I added NPN version which is easy to control with wide range voltages.

Comment: thank you very much michal. could you explain how the circuit works especially the pnp version.

Comment: After you turn the switch the PNP transistor is immediately ON (Led also). Its beacause the The Cap is discharged (0V) so base of PNP is connected like to GND via R3. Then the Cap starts to charge via R2 (R3 also). After while when the Cap reaches about 4.3V the drop between emitter and base is less than 0.7V.

Comment: So the PNP becomes OFF (Led also). When you turn off the switch the Cap starts to discharge via D2 and R4 to 0V to be ready to repeat power cycle.

Answer (score 1):

You can measure the LED voltage with an ADC with the LED state forced ‘on’. This should correspond to the Vf for that LED.

You could also use a current mirror to check the LED ‘on’ current, and measure that.